# Блокировка пункта в Spinner

Tags: android

```
final MaterialSpinner spinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setItems(ANDROID_VERSIONS);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, final int position, long id, String item) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (position == 1) {

                }
                if (position == 2) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Есть `spinner`, нужно чтобы при открытии меню например 3 пункт был блокирован не нажимался, как реализовать?

Comment: нужен кастомный адаптер, который будет отдельно обрабатывать нужную позицию (блокировать ее)

Answer (score 0):

```
itemView.setClickable(! position == 2);
itemView.setEnabled(! position == 2);
itemText.setTextColor(position == 2 ? Color.GRAY : Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: не совсем то что нужно, 3 пункт нажимается а потом блокируется,а мне надо при открытии меню чтоб 3 пункт изначально не нажимался

Comment: А вы где код этот разместили? Скиньте код адаптера спиннера в вопрос